# Basis and rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

My professor assigned this question and I am a bit confused by the wording of it.

Find (a) a basis for the row space and (b) rank of the matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}2&5\\-2&-5\\-6&-15\end{bmatrix}

There is only one pivot row, r<sub>1</sub> so the rank is one. What I don't understand is finding a basis for the row space.
- There isn't a basis for the row spaces in the vector space of M<sub>3,2</sub> matrices because there is only one pivot row.
- Since there is only one pivot row, then the row space can only be a basis for M<sub>1,2</sub> right?

Comment: the vector given by the first row is a basis, the row space is one dimensional. In general, you find the row echelon form, whatever you might call it, and the nonzero rows give a basis, and the row rank is just the number of such nonzero rows

Comment: the only nonzero row in reduced row echelon form is the first row, (1,2.5,0). So this is the basis for the row space of the above matrix?

Comment: yes.................

Comment: Is there a difference between being (1,2.5,0) and (1,2.5)? I think the answer should actually be (1,2,5) because there are only two elements in the matrix. I got the 0 from reducing to row echelon form from the augmented matrix, but I don't think I needed to do that step

Comment: I did not notice the $0,$ which is wrong. The basis vector is either your $(1,\frac{5}{2})$ or the original $(2,5).$ I suggest you stick with your $(1,\frac{5}{2})$ as it comes directly from the echelon form

Comment: okay, thank you for the clarification. It's because reducing with the augmented matrix is only to check for linear independence right?

Answer (score 1):

Before we begin, let's define something first:

1. Let the matrix in your question denoted as $A$.
2. Let the row space of $A$ denoted as $RS(A)$.
3. RREF is the abbreviation of *reduced row echelon form*, which is the result of Gauss-Jordan elimination.
4. Given any tuple $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$:

   - It can be seen as
     $\left[
       \begin{array}{c}
        a\\ b
       \end{array}
      \right]\in\mathbb R^{2\times1}$
   - It can be seen as
     $\left[
       \begin{array}{r}
        a, b
       \end{array}
      \right]\in\mathbb R^{1\times2}$
   - So let's just use $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$ to mean one of them that makes sense ***in the context***.

---

*["] There isn't a basis for the row spaces in the vector space of M3,2 matrices because there is only one pivot row [."]*

- By definition of row space, it's the ***span*** of the rows of $A$, which is a ***subspace*** of $\mathbb R^2$(or $\mathbb R^{1\times2}$ as explained above) so it must has a basis.
- $\dim \mathbb R^2=2,$ and $\dim RS(A)=1$, no contradiction.
- $(2,5)$ is not a basis of $\mathbb R^2$.
- $(2,5)$ ***is*** a basis of $RS(A)$.

*["] Since there is only one pivot row, then the row space can only be a basis for M1,2 right? [."]*

- $\textrm{One pivot row in RREF}$ $\iff$ $\textrm{rank}(A)=1$.
- Basis is a set of vector(s) that spans a (sub)space.
- Row space is a subspace, which means it contains $\mathbf 0$, so it cannot be a basis.

From the comment, you might also consider some questions/issues:

- Why turning $A$ into RREF doesn't change the $RS(A)$?
- Why you said the first row in RREF is $(1,2.5,0)\in\mathbb R^3$? It should still be in $\mathbb R^2$.
- The difference is that $(1,2.5)\in\mathbb R^2$ and $(1,2.5,0)\in\mathbb R^3$.